# How long does Route 53 A record take to update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, with Route 53 A record pointing to the beanstalk configured load balancer.

There were some problems with my old beanstalk environment, so I am creating a new one and now need to point my Route 53 A record to the new beanstalk load balancer. Is there a way I can check how long does it take for this change to take place? Or if there is a way to know if it has already taken place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used the A record and alias feature of Route53 it should be within a minute (all our [TTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) setting for alias A records in AWS are 59 seconds by default).

If you would like to make sure it points to the new one, I recommend [dig](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/dig-command-examples/) both load balancers directly to get the current ips and then dig to your domain to see which ip the alias record currently points to.

Comment: I did use the ALIAS. but just to be sure I am trying to `dig` like you suggested. When I `dig` my load balancers, they give two answers because I have 2 instances in my load balancers. It doesnt seem to show the IP of the load balancer.

Comment: It might show you more then one ip address but it should never be the ip address from the EC2s. Those are the loadbalancer ips. I have up to 30EC2s behind a loadbalancer and only see 2 or 3 IPs. Also the loadbalancer IPs will not show up in the list of your elastic ips.

Comment: so I should be able to match the IP answer of `dig domain.com` to the IP answer of `dig aws-eb-etcetcetc.elb.amazonaws.com`? because both IPs seem to be different now.

Comment: Instead of dig, try ping and take the IP and compare those.